# SQL equation in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do something like the following with sql? This statement is not flagged as having an error, but isn't working correctly anyhow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Orders` 
WHERE  `TotalCost` -  `TotalPaid` +  `TotalRefunded` 
BETWEEN 1 
AND 1000
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what is not working correctly. If just made a mockup table with some sample data, if gives the result I'd expect.

Comment: Yes. Are you having any problem with it?

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. It is actually working, I was having a slow "moment".

Answer (score 4):

This is a guess.  You should really edit the question with sample data.  But my guess is that `TotalRefunded` is often `NULL`.  So you should handle `NULL`s in the arithmetic computation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Orders` 
WHERE (coalesce(`TotalCost`, 0) -  coalesce(`TotalPaid`, 0) +  coalesce(`TotalRefunded`, 0)) 
          BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

check your operations once, and write WHERE CLAUSE accordingly, not sure what you want...Also for error part , try this as

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.TotalCost - Orders.TotalPaid + Orders.TotalRefunded 
BETWEEN 1 
AND 1000
```

Also write Where clause nicely, and put brackets wherever necessary, as per the need of your problem.

Hope this helps....